# Ajuda com funcao urlencode

Tags: php

como eu consigo fazer com que essa função alem de colocar + nos espaços colocar -, e que ela troque o `%7C` por `|` alguém saberia? somente na `url`

Abaixo o Modelo de como esta:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

gostaria que na `url` ficasse algo do tipo:

Casamento-joao-+-Maria-|-Ensaio

Comment: estou usando, mas ela me traz desse jeito a `url` como o da img e eu nao queria assim gostaria de algo como especificado abaixo da img

Comment: No meu entendimento, a pergunta é fora de escopo por pedir uma solução tecnicamente inviável, e que não tem condição de funcionar na prática, tampouco ser aproveitada por outro usuário.

Answer (score 2):

**Não recomendo você fazer isso**, pois o `urlencode` é feito para garantir a interoperabilidade entre o browser e a aplicação, e a decodificação correta depende dos caracteres estarem devidamente codificados (senão, nem seria necessário o `urlencode`).

De qualquer forma, isso só vai causar problemas, e ao recuperar o valor pela aplicação PHP, **não será retornado o que você está esperando**.

Mas se é isso que quer, segue uma maneira de mudar o URL:

```
$url = str_replace( '%7C', '|', $url );
$url = str_replace( '+', '-', $url );
$url = str_replace( '%2B', '+', $url );
```

Veja o resultado rodando conforme pedido no **[IDEONE](http://ideone.com/9Gs9Qp)**

Sintaxe alternativa:

```
$de   = array( '%7C', '+', '%2B' ); // acrescente todos os
$para = array( '|'  , '-', '+'   ); // pares que quiser trocar
$url = str_replace( $de, $para, $url );
```

Função:

```
function leonardo_encode( $url ) {
   $de   = array( '%7C', '+', '%2B' );
   $para = array( '|'  , '-', '+'   );

   return str_replace( $de, $para, urlencode( $url ) );
}
```

### `rawurlencode` vs `urlencode`

Importante considerar que para o que você está fazendo, o `rawurlencode` seria mais apropriado que o `urlencode`.

- `urlencode` normalmente se usa quando você está mexendo com a *query string*, ou valores de post:

  ```
  http://example.com/recurso?nome=dados+codificados
                                  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  ```
- `rawurlencode` normalmente se usa quando você está mexendo com o caminho/nome do recurso do URL:

  ```
  http://example.com/recurso/dados%20codificados
                             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  ```

Comment: tipo assim não tem como eu trocar dentro da função isso? somente os espaço que são `%20` trocar eles por `-` e não como padrão que e `+`, pois vou precisar do sinal de `+`

Comment: Não, a função serve pra fazer o encoding correto. Note que você pode trocar o que quiser, basta colocar o %20 na esquerda, e o '-' na direita no `str_replace`. Nada impede de voce criar uma função `leonardo_encode` e usar o código acima dentro da sua função. Notar que o + está sendo preservado na 3a linha, se você visualizar o teste no [IDEONE](http://ideone.com/9Gs9Qp) vai ver que eu fiz exatamente o que você pediu na pergunta.

Comment: sim eu percebi estou tentando fazer a funcao para a troca

Comment: O problema maior vai começar na hora que você for recuperar esses dados pelo PHP